# How to define json schema by rules on elements in python code?

Tags: python, jsonschema

I am in the process of defining a json schema which is quite complex and nested. I am planning to use multiple schema files to keep schema cleaner and partitioned by major sections and use `$ref` to combine them all into one. The validator functions I have can already handle this and I have tested with couple smaller toy schema examples.

The question I have is that I have only a single example of json, so, I am not capable to infer schema from example only since a lot of elements have regex patterns and min-max conditions. What I have is a tabular map of all elements with their name, type, valid ranges ...
I have looked up different json schema generators (GenSON, jsonschema.net ...) from data instances and examples.

As an example, consider the logic/rules below for a json schema elements:

```
Level   Element       Type     ...   Pattern   ... (exclusive) min  (exclusive) max     default
1       VersionDate   string        ([0-9]{8}) 
1       Pairs         array
2       a             integer  ...                     False    0                       0 
2       b             number   ...                     False    0.0    False     99.5   0
2       c             number   ...                     False    0.0    True      10000  0
```

What I would like to have is a clean way to parse the lines of the above table and add to the json schema object in a programmatical way. The reason for that is to be able to have a reproducible schema generator where I can tweak or move things around.

I would appreciate any hint/suggestions.

```
{
  "VersionDate": {
    "$id": "#/properties/VersionDate",
    "type": "string",
    "title": "The Versiondate Schema",
    "examples": [
      "20160319"
    ],
    "pattern": "^([0-9]{8})$"
  },
  "Pairs": {
    "$id": "#/properties/Pairs",
    "type": "array",
    "title": "The PairsSchema",
    "items": {
      "$id": "#/properties/Pairs/items",
      "type": "object",
      "title": "The Items Schema",
      "required": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "a": {
          "$id": "#/properties/Pairs/items/properties/a",
          "type": "integer",
          "title": "The a Schema",
          "default": 0,
          "examples": [
            1234
          ],
          "minimum": 0
        },
        "b": {
          "$id": "#/properties/Pairs/items/properties/b",
          "type": "number",
          "title": "The b Schema",
          "default": 0,
          "examples": [
            30.1
          ],
          "minimum": 0,
          "maximum": 99.5
        },
        "c": {
          "$id": "#/properties/Pairs/items/properties/c",
          "type": "number",
          "title": "The c Schema",
          "default": 0,
          "examples": [
            4.98
          ],
          "minimum": 0,
          "exclusivemaximum": 10000
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `marshmallow` library. It has got validation as well.

Comment: Why do you want to generate schemas from a format you created? Schema generators are often unnecessarily noisy. Why not just write the schemas themsevles?

Comment: Thanks @MeysamAzad, I will check it out.

Comment: @Relequestual, The format (rule table) I have is not strict in the sense of format. So, I am flexible to change that. My main concern is to reduce human error by directly find/replacing in json schema file, say if the regex pattern or min/max of an element change, if that make sense. The structure perhaps would not change at all but the limit values and templates might down the road.

Comment: In which case, you may be interested in JSONNET https://jsonnet.org - UK Gov are a big user for constructing their JSON Schema using JSONnet